Powershell howto Filter XML Nodes
I'm searching for a way to filter XML-Files. I couldn't find a good tutorial, so I ask here:
for that here a small exmaple XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project>
    <AdditionalInformation>
        <Attribute Name="YEAR" AttributeDataType="xs:int">
            <Value>2024</Value>
        </Attribute>    
    
    </AdditionalInformation>
    <element ID="123546" Name="axis">
        <Attribute Name="Axe-Info" AttributeDataType="xs:string">
            <Value>Rack</Value>
        </Attribute>
        <element ID="58655" >   
            <Attribute Name="level" AttributeDataType="xs:string">
                <Value>X</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="direction" AttributeDataType="xs:string">
                <Value>left</Value>
            </Attribute>
            
        </element>
                <element ID="58658" >   
            <Attribute Name="level" AttributeDataType="xs:string">
                <Value>Y</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="direction" AttributeDataType="xs:string">
                <Value>right</Value>
            </Attribute>
            
        </element>
        <element ID="58685" >   
            <Attribute Name="level" AttributeDataType="xs:string">
                <Value>Z</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="direction" AttributeDataType="xs:string">
                <Value>left</Value>
            </Attribute>
        </element>
        <element ID="586888" >  
            <Attribute Name="angle" AttributeDataType="xs:string">
                <Value>horizontal</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="position" AttributeDataType="xs:int">
                <Value>185</Value>
            </Attribute>
        </element>
        <element ID="5899858" > 
            <Attribute Name="angle" AttributeDataType="xs:string">
                <Value>vertical</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="position" AttributeDataType="xs:int">
                <Value>152</Value>
            </Attribute>
        </element>
    </element>
    <element ID="128546" Name="engine">
        <Attribute Name="Eng-Info" AttributeDataType="xs:string">
            <Value>Rack</Value>
        </Attribute>
        <element ID="5865855" > 
            <Attribute Name="power" AttributeDataType="xs:int">
                <Value>400</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="unit" AttributeDataType="xs:string">
                <Value>kW</Value>
            </Attribute>
        </element>
        <element ID="5865155" > 
            <Attribute Name="power" AttributeDataType="xs:int">
                <Value>200</Value>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="unit" AttributeDataType="xs:string">
                <Value>kW</Value>
            </Attribute>
        </element>
    </element>


</project>

In End I'd like to have the following Information:

x,left
Y,right
Z,left

For That I've to Filter first the element-node with the Name "axis".
Then I have to filter alle element-nodes which have an attribute-Node with the Name "level"
How can I do that filtering operations in Powershell?
Thanks

Perhaps something like this, find all nodes with Attribute Name equal to level and from there look for their next sibling to get the direction value, so:
$xml = [xml]::new()
$xml.Load('path\to\theXML.xml')
$xml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name='level']") | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Level     = $_.Value
        Direction = $_.NextSibling.Value
    }
}

This would produce this output using the sample XML:
Level Direction
----- ---------
X     left
Y     right
Z     left

Another approach a bit more hacky, this would produce array of strings instead of objects:
$i = $true
$xml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name='level' or @Name='direction']").Value |
    ForEach-Object { if ($i = -not $i) { "$prev, $_" }; $prev = $_ }

# X, left
# Y, right
# Z, left

